# Sorting a multidiD array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, integer

I have a multi dimensional array that has 3 elements in each index.

Example `[[bob,12,white],[alex,2,hispanic]]`

How can I sort the array by the integer age (middle value)?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You can pass a function to determine how your array should be sorted.

```js
const sorted = [
  ['bob',12,'white'],
  ['alex',2,'hispanic']
].sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]) // sorts by integer age asc

console.log(sorted)
```